# How can I solve $e^x=\frac 1{x+5}$?

Tags: exponentiation, lambert-w

How can I solve

$$e^x=\frac 1{x+5}$$

I tried

$$xe^x+5e^x=1$$

$$xe^x=1-5e^x$$

$$W(xe^x)=W(1-5e^x)$$

$$W(1-5x)=x$$

But, I stucked here. I need to find the real solutions.

Answer (score 9):

**HINT**

Multiply both side $e^5$, then you get

$$
\begin{align}e^{x+5}=\frac {e^5}{x+5}&\implies (x+5)e^{x+5}=e^5\\
&\implies x+5=W(e^5)\end{align}
$$